# Arranging dynamically divs related to other divs

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page where I load 6 blog posts, 
and I have a button which loads more blog posts.

One blog post looks like this:

[image]

At page load it looks fine, but after I press the `Load More button` the styling is gone, and it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using. I use separate `div`-s for the image, for the title, for the content, and for some reason when the `Load More` button is pressed and loads the new posts, for the new posts the styling is not ok. Can you please provide me some examples how to arrange `divs` related to another `div`? Can I do this without javascript, with pure css ot in this case I need javascript? Thanks!

```css
.loop-entry:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.loop-entry-thumbnail {
 max-height: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.loop-entry-case-study-thumbnail {
 width: 100%;
    max-height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loop-entry-title {
 max-height: 115px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.loop-entry-excerpt h3{
  margin-top: -12px !important;
}

.loop-entry-excerpt h3 span{
     margin-top: 28px !important; 
}

.loop-entry-excerpt p,
.loop-entry-excerpt h3
{
  margin-top: 90px;
  color: rgb(119, 119, 119) !important;
  font-family: "Oswald" !important;
  font-size: 1.1em !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 23.8px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  /* max-height: 150px;*/
}

.page-id-61 .loop-entry-title {
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 30px;
 position: absolute;
 /*top: 50px;*/
}
.loop-entry-content {
    padding: 0px 30px 0 30px;
    /*color: #777;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
 font-family: "Oswald";
 font-size: 15.4px;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 23.8px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
.blog-posts img {
 height: 175px;
 width: 350px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="contact_con blog-posts">
                    
                        <div class="loop-entry-thumbnail">
                            <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/marketing-millennials-dont-trust-stereotypes/" title="Marketing to Millennials: Don’t Trust the Stereotypes">
                                <img src="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_404838631.jpg" alt="Marketing to Millennials: Don’t Trust the Stereotypes" title="Marketing to Millennials: Don’t Trust the Stereotypes" width="100%">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                         <div class="loop-entry-content clr" style="position: relative;">
                            <header>
                                <h2 class="loop-entry-title entry-title">
                                    <a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/marketing-millennials-dont-trust-stereotypes/">Marketing to Millennials: Don’t Trust ...</a>
                                </h2>
                            </header>
            
                            <div class="loop-entry-excerpt entry clr" style="/*! top: 73px; *//*! margin-top: 40px; */position: absolute;">
                                Today’s modern market looks drastically different than it used to, whether it be th...<br>
                                <span class="home_readmore"><a href="http://staging.princetonpartners.com/marketing-millennials-dont-trust-stereotypes/">Read more</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: CSS and HTML wouldn't do this. Post your related Javascript as well and make sure it replicates the error. Using an online editor like CODEPEN or JFiddle that is debuggable may help

Comment: can you share the link to the web page?

Comment: In the screenshot, you have something applying `position: absolute` to `loop-entry-excerpt`. That is the problem.

Comment: @Luis Brazilva-I don't have any javascript code yet. I can't see either the method for the LoadMore button, I need to resolve without this.